# Receiver type 'UIView' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'addAnimation:forKey:'

Tags: objective-c

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation; 
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
theAnimation.duration=0.5;
theAnimation.repeatCount=0;
theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
//[self.quntityView animationDidStart:theAnimation];
[self.quntityView addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`addAnimation:forKey:` is a method on CALayer. You can't just call it on a UIView.

Try:

```
[self.quntityView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Comment: [self.quntityView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"]; Using this line the view is animated correctly and it is too slow.How can speed a view while it appear..

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean. You've asked for a duration of half a second — is the animation taking longer than half a second?